# Does the Resistance know R2-D2 has the rest of the map?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Does the Resistance know that the rest of the map to find

> Luke

is in R2-D2? (but despite knowing that they can't get it as he is in low power mode essentially).

Or do they not even know it's there?

I think I remember C-3P0 mentioning something about how it's in there but they can't get it, but may be mistaken.

Comment: Got the canon answer for you :)

Comment: I must say, using a spoiler tag in this case seems silly, considering the title of the question already spoils a plot point, and the post appears in the sidebar. I am lucky I have already seen the film -- otherwise just seeing the title of the post in the "Hot Network Questions" section of the sidebar might have ruined the surprise for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- ### NO.

  **They don't even know the map Poe was supposed to retrieve wasn't the whole map in the first place**. This is what happens in the novelization by Alan Dean Foster when they **first** see that map:

  > Reaching in, C-3PO removed a tiny device. Turning, he inserted it into a matching slot in the multi-sided table-projector that dominated the center of the room. Immediately, a three-dimensional map filled the space above the flat-topped apparatus with stars, nebulae, and other stellar phenomena. Leia studied the display intently. **But though her eyes roved knowledgably through the compacted cosmos, she failed to find what she was looking for. Her dissatisfaction was unmistakable**.
  >
  > While he was in his own way equally disappointed, C-3PO was not programmed to display it. Instead, he merely expressed a rational regret.
  >
  > **“General, while I have already completed a preliminary analysis, I’ll inform you of my final determination only when I have finished comparing the information available in this map to that in our full database. There. I’ve finished. Unfortunately, I have to conclude that this map contains insufficient data with which to make a match to any system in our records.”**
  >
  > From a corner, Han spoke up. “Told you.”
  > Leia ignored him. “**What a fool I was to think we could just find Luke and bring him back.**”

---

- This is confirmed by earlier events as well: Poe discusses the whole map (not a missing fragment) with Tekka:

  > “Legend says this map is unobtainable,” Poe noted. “How’d you do it?”

  and when talking to Finn:

  > “My droid’s got a map that leads to Luke Skywalker.”
- Obviously, the fact that the map is incomplete is news to Finn, Rey and Han and BB-8, because they just go by what Poe told Finn:

  > Dutifully, the droid rolled into a suitable position. A lens brightened, and abruptly the lounge was all but filled with an enormously detailed and complex star map. Nebulae, solo stars, translucent splashes of concentrated dark matter, and entire solar systems were displayed before them. Even Chewbacca sat up to have a better look. Finn was impressed and Rey in awe — **but Han found himself frowning**.
  > Moving forward and into the three-dimensional representation, he tracked system positions and locator stars. One finger traced the outlines of a particularly bright and well-known nebular cluster. Like everything else in the map, it was brilliantly depicted.
  > **It was also only half there.**
  > He turned to the others. “This is accurate, **but it’s not complete. It’s just a piece. I can tell from the location of the breaks and from what’s only partially shown**.” He grunted softly. “Ever since Luke disappeared, people have been looking for him.”

---

- And as a final nail, we find out at the end that **Poe was told by Kylo Ren that it's only a partial map**

  > Never one to defer in the presence of superiors, Poe spoke first.
  > “**Kylo Ren said that the segment held by Beebee-Ate is the last piece of the map that shows the way to Skywalker’s location. So, where’s the rest of it?**”
  > “The First Order has it.” Rey looked over at him. “They extracted it from the Imperial archives.”
  > Poe stared at her. “The Empire?”
  > Admiral Statura nodded in agreement. “**It makes sense**. The Empire would have been looking for the first Jedi temples. In destroying all the Jedi sanctuaries they would have acquired a great deal of peripheral information.”

  ### Note that Statura basically admits that they had no idea and he's just agreeing with Poe out of pure logic, not prior knowledge.

---

- Having said that, BB-8, for some unfathomable reason DOES seem to thing R2-D2 has the rest of the map, though it's not explained in canon as to why (to be clear, he only knows about the "rest of the map" because Rey and company viewed it earlier with him, while en route).

  This happens right after Poe and Finn reunite:

  > **THE SEARCH HAD taken BB-8 some time, but he finally found what he was looking for.** Or rather, who. Or maybe both, since an intelligent droid technically qualified as both a who and a what. In the dark, dusty storeroom **he rolled over to the R2 unit and beeped a greeting, the transmission sequence too rapid and too exhaustive for any human to follow**. It didn’t matter. There was no response from the immobile R2 unit.
  > BB-8 tried again, utilizing a different droid language. When that also failed, he moved forward and gave the other mechanical a forceful nudge. Like everything else, that too failed to generate a response.
  > Observing the unsuccessful interaction, C-3PO came forward out of the shadows.
  > “You’re wasting your time, I’m afraid. **It is very doubtful that Artoo would have the rest of the map in his backup data**.” When BB-8 queried the protocol droid, C-3PO responded without hesitation.

  Just to be clear, the idea wasn't C-3PO's, he merely figured it out from what BB-8 was saying.

Comment: In the movie there's a line where the First Order folks mention that they had retrieved the rest of the map from old Imperial archives. That to me implies they clearly **did** in fact realize that it was only part of the map. If the novelization says differently, then it looks to me like you've found a point of divergence.

Comment: @T.E.D. - well, Poe also gets this info from Kilo Ren, so there's a chance they are merely being imprecise in that quote too. I'll remove for clarity.

Comment: [Word of God](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-answers-burning-question-about-r2-d2-star-wars-force-awakens) says R2-D2 got the map when he plugged into the Death Star.

Comment: @DVK Go for it!

Comment: @DVK Saw the film again yesterday and you are correct, have marked this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I think it's pretty clear they don't; Leia, for her part, seems extremely disappointed that the map is only a piece. At no point does anyone go "wait, that looks like it fits into R2-D2's map!" They also don't seem to have any idea why R2-D2 has shut down or what will wake him up.

I've also heard the idea that BB-8 knew and no one listened to him, but I'm skeptical there too. Plenty of people in the Resistance speak BB-8's language, and I'm pretty sure if he told them "I know where the rest of the map is," someone would have paid attention.

I *think* we're supposed to interpret part of Rey's flashback in the cantina, which shows

> Luke putting his hand on R2

as the map being uploaded into the droid, along with the command to shut down until

> Rey (or at least another Force user)

comes back to claim it.

Comment: I assumed that they knew R2 had the rest of the map but hadn't seen it as they couldn't get access to it.

Comment: If they had, they likely would have just plugged R2 in and pulled it from his databanks.

Comment: @pros-cons Leia's disappointment when the map is only partial, and her comments that it doesn't look like any system she's seen, makes me assume they didn't know there was a pre-existing "partial map" in the first place.

Comment: [Word of God](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-answers-burning-question-about-r2-d2-star-wars-force-awakens) says R2-D2 got the map when he plugged into the Death Star.

Comment: boo. it also says that BB-8 did wake up R2. lame.

Answer (score 1):

BB-8 seemed to think that RD-D2 has the rest of the map, but C-3PO dismissed that idea and after that mentioning that if it was in fact true, that it would be useless because R2-D2 was in low power mode.

So they resistance might have hoped that R2-D2 has the map, but they couldn't activate him. So I guess they didn't know.